# How to apply both tooltip and highlight to textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, textarea, highlight

Is there a way to add tooltip to highlighted part of textarea?

I have already done highlighting part of textarea by https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR

I tried to add `<ReactTooltip>` to highlighted text

But it didn't work

`<ReactTooltip>` wasn't able to receive `mouseover` trigger because of `<textarea>`

Also if I applied `pointer-events: none;` to `<textarea>` the `<ReactTooltip>` worked but then `<textarea>` didn't work

Is there any possible way to apply both highlight and tooltip to `<textarea>`?

Here's part of my code:

```
<div className="text-area">
    <div className="backdrop">
        <div className="highlights">
            This is 
            <span className="highlight" data-tip data-for="tooltip-span">highlighted</span>
            <ReactTooltip id="tooltip-span">
                <span>My comment!</span>
            </ReactTooltip>
             text.
        </div>
    </div>
    <textarea>
        This is highlighted text.
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!